# Changing background color of tab content with MaterializeCSS

Tags: css, materialize

I have been trying to change the background color of the content of tabs using the MaterializeCSS tabs - http://materializecss.com/tabs.html

If you check the website - you can see that the default tabs are white but the background color of the 'Test 1, Test2, etc.' content is the same greyish color as the rest of the website. I want to duplicate this but have been unable to. Every time I try to change the CSS, I somehow also mess up the appearance of the tabs themselves. I was hoping someone could help me setup the CSS correctly. Below is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

  <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--Import materialize.css-->
  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.99.0/css/materialize.min.css">
  <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- Tabs -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12">
        <ul class="tabs">
          <li class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#test1">Tab 1</a></li>
          <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test2">Tab 2</a></li>
          <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test3">Tab 3</a></li>
          <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test4">Tab 4</a></li>
          <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test5">Tab 5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="test1" class="col s12">Test 1</div>
      <div id="test2" class="col s12">Test 2</div>
      <div id="test3" class="col s12">Test 3</div>
      <div id="test4" class="col s12">Test 2</div>
      <div id="test5" class="col s12">Test 3</div>
    </div>

    <!-- Init Tabs -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('ul.tabs').tabs();
          });
        </script>


    <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.99.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

I have been trying to edit all the classes and for instance the 'test1' ID. But this will also conflict with the bottom of the tabs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you be more clear please? Do you want the highlighted one to be darker than the other?

Comment: I want to change the background color of the content Div's (with ID 'test1-test5). By default the background color is white. On the website you can see that the background color is grey - so I know it is possible to change. I just haven't been able to change the CSS in such a way that it doesn't interfere with the layout of the clickable tabs.

Comment: from What I understood,I've update the answer.Please do let me know if it needs any update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

  <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--Import materialize.css-->
  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.99.0/css/materialize.min.css">
  <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

  </head>
  <style>
 li:nth-child(n+1){background-color:#ccc;}
 #test1, #test2, #test3, #test4, #test5{background-color:pink;}
  </style>
  <body>

    <!-- Tabs -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12">
        <ul class="tabs">
          <li class="tab col s2"><a class="active" href="#test1">Tab 1</a></li>
          <li class="tab col s2"><a href="#test2">Tab 2</a></li>
          <li class="tab col s2"><a href="#test3">Tab 3</a></li>
          <li class="tab col s2"><a href="#test4">Tab 4</a></li>
          <li class="tab col s2"><a href="#test5">Tab 5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="test1" class="col s12">Test 1</div>
      <div id="test2" class="col s12">Test 2</div>
      <div id="test3" class="col s12">Test 3</div>
      <div id="test4" class="col s12">Test 4</div>
      <div id="test5" class="col s12">Test 5</div>
    </div>

    <!-- Init Tabs -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('ul.tabs').tabs();
          });
        </script>


    <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.99.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

You meant something like this? First of all the col value should some up to 12 you have given has 3 *5 =15.

Comment: Thank you for this. I am not trying to change the color of the tabs themselves (the way you change the li tags to #ccc. I am exactly trying to change the background color for the id's Test 1 to Test 5. However the solution here doesn't work for me. I do not see the pink color.

Comment: In that case you can simply use #test1{background-color:red;},it should work.I've added the pink color to the div id test1 to test5,run the snipet.which browser are you using?